# Give an expression that describe the language generated by this grammar

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

the grammar:[image]

I tried to breakdown the problem but i am not sure what the end result expression could be.

I have to give an expression and try to describe this grammar.

Here's what i did for now :

I see that there's two possible starting words ( S non-terminal means start)

For $S \Rightarrow WTba$ i get :

$W^*\$(ba)^*ba$

W can be Wb or ab so we know the word will start by ab for sure : $ab(b^*(ab)^*)^*\$(ba)^*ba$

For $S \Rightarrow abUV$ i get :

$ab(ab)^*\$V$
since V can be Va or ba the word will end by ba for sure : $ab(ab)^*\$(a^*(ba)^*)^*ba $

From these two end result i can see that  they are ALMOST the reversed language of each other but one has the letter b instead of a in the big loop $(a^*(ba)^*)^*$ vs $(b^*(ab)^*)^*$

But i can't manage to figure out a general expression and correctly describe this grammar, so if anyone could help out it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you’ve lost the relationship between the part to the left of the $\$$ and the part to the right of it: you cannot express it in terms of Kleene stars. For instance, when you apply the production $T\to WTba$ $n$ times, you get the same number of $W$s as you do $ba$s, so you don’t get $W^*T(ba)^*$.

First, it’s clear that the language produced by $W$ is $abb^*$: the only possible derivations starting with $W$ have the form

$$W\Rightarrow^nWb^n\Rightarrow abb^n$$

for $n\ge 0$. Now let’s look at a derivation that starts by using the production $S\to WTba$. Since we know what $W$ does, we should concentrate on $T$: we can apply the production $T\to WTba$ $n$ times for any $n\ge 0$, but eventually we must apply $T\to\$$ in order to get rid of the $T$. Thus, we get derivations of the form

$$S\Rightarrow WTba\Rightarrow^n WW^nT(ba)^nba\Rightarrow WW^n\$(ba)^nba$$

for each $n\ge 0$. This will evidently generate the language described by the expression

$$(abb^*)^n\$(ba)^n\,,\tag{1}$$

where $n$ can be any **positive** integer.

The other half of the language can be analyzed similarly. $V$ generates everything of the form $baa^*$, so we end up with everything of the form

$$(ab)^n\$(baa^*)^n\tag{2}$$

for $n\ge 1$. Let $L_1$ be the language described by $(1)$ and $L_2$ the language described by $(2)$, so that we want the language $L=L_1\cup L_2$. $L$ can be described in just this way, but the description can perhaps be made a little nicer if we notice that $L_2$ can be obtained from $L_1$ (and *vice versa*) in a fairly simple way. Let

$$f:\{a,b\}\to\{a,b\}:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
a,&\text{if }x=b\\
b,&\text{if }x=a\,,
\end{cases}$$

and let $\hat f$ be the natural extension of $f$ to $\{a,b\}^*$. (E.g., $\hat f:(abbbab)=baaaba$.) Then

$$L_2=\{\hat f(v)\$\hat f(u):u\$v\in L_1\}\,,$$

and

$$L_1=\{\hat f(v)\$\hat f(u):u\$v\in L_2\}\,.$$

Thus, $L$ can be described simply in terms of $(1)$ and $\hat f$.